# how to Simulate semaphores with message passing...?

Tags: algorithm

I want to simulate the semaphores (wait and signal procedure) with the message passing just in form of algorithm (and not code).

can anyone help me...?

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to know the algorithms with which  critical-sections and semaphores primitives are implemented?  See   [Process Synchronization](http://titus.compsci.ualr.edu/~ptang/3380/slides/lec3.pdf) (pdf).  Note that sometimes you may see a semaphore implemented using critical-sections to ensure atomicity of the test-modify operations.

Message queuing is built on top of synchronization primitives.  The message queue you seek is in Chapter 4 of the excellent [Little Book of Semaphores](http://greenteapress.com/semaphores/) ([pdf](http://greenteapress.com/semaphores/downey08semaphores.pdf)).

*Edited to add:*

I have to guess what you mean by "mailbox," so if this answer is no good, it'd be helpful for you to define what a mailbox is.  Do I understand that the exercise is to implement P and V by using a high-level synchronization mechanism such as a message queue?  Since a message queue is by necessity protected against concurrency issues, that's a simple exercise.

Given a class Mailbox which is guaranteed to be thread-safe and which has these methods:

- enqueue(message) - Add a message to the mailbox.  If there any threads blocked in dequeue, wake one.
- dequeue - Remove a message from the mailbox, blocking if the mailbox is empty.

Then a semaphore class would have these methods:

```
initialize(count):
  mailbox = Mailbox.new
  count.times do
    v

v:
  mailbox.enqueue(any_message)

p:
  mailbox.dequeue
```

any_message is any message at all.  It doesn't matter what it is, since we're only using the message queue to wake up blocked threads.

This algorithm emulates a semaphore which cannot have a negative value.  A semaphore which can be created with a negative value will need to do more work.  Which do you need?

Comment: I know a little about algorithm of semaphores (wait and signal algorithms).
I don't know how to simulate the semaphore's queue with mailbox.
when we say in wait procedure that :

semaphore.count--;

if (semaphore.count < 0)
    place this process in semaphore.queue and block this process

and when we say in siganl procedure that :

semaphore.count++;

if (semaphore.count <= 0)
    remove process p from semaphore.queue and place in ready list

Now How should I do these with mailbox?
where processes must be placed?

Comment: Hamed, I added to the answer.

Comment: Yes, a Semaphore with negative value (for mutual exclusion).
Where the threads should be placed? (when we add a message to mailbox, where is a thread waked up from?)
Should we consider a queue for threads, just like Semaphore?

Comment: Mutex works fine in a semaphore that cannot be initialized with a negative value.  Threads are normally put into a plain old FIFO (first in, first out) queue by P; V removes threads from the queue and wakes them up.

Hamed, I think there is a language barrier between us.  I've got the impression that you and I are using words that don't have the same meaning to the other person.  Can you please define these terms?:  "message queue," "mailbox," "queue."